# Open Folder on IE using javascript (CRM 4.0)?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-4

I want to see my specific folder on IE window.i use window.open(); and then i get an error "Access denied".I gave "everyone" permission on this folder and share it.

```
var oShell = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var Path="C:\\test\\"+crmForm.ObjectId;
  if (! oShell.FolderExists(Path) )
{
  oShell.CreateFolder(Path)
}    

crmForm.all.new_paylasim.DataValue=Path;
var urlField =crmForm.all.new_paylasim;

urlField.style.color = 0x0000ff;

urlField.style.textDecorationUnderline = true;

urlField.style.cursor = "hand";

urlField.ondblclick = function() {

var url = urlField.DataValue; // Or get it from somewhere else

if (url != null && url.length > 0) {
window.open(url);

}
}
```

What's solution?

Comment: You would like to open Windows Explorer?. Show the code for window.open()

Comment: @ckeller - window.open() is a standard browser function.

Comment: when i try window.open(<websiteurl>); it works,but how can i open folder ?

Comment: @pap: I know ;) I was interested in the parameters...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to problems

1. the security model of IE has changed and window.open with a local file path does IMHO not work anymore. See also [Ie 8.0 Access Denied When Trying To Open Local Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339734/ie-8-0-access-denied-when-trying-to-open-local-files)
2. Your file uri is not correct. It should be either `file:///C:/myfile.txt` (which doesn't work anymore) or `file://server/share` for a network share. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2006/12/06/file-uris-in-windows.aspx

Create a network share for the folder you would like to open.

Comment: i could't solve it... my link is like this: //crmsvr/share/My%20Documents%2010  when i copy this to ie address space,it works.But i create it to link on my form,it cant works and says "make sure the path or internet adress"

Comment: yea i write file://. i think i have to define permissions on ie