# Embedded HTA in xslt stylesheet

Tags: xml, xslt, hta

Given the problem I have:

[[Ie 8.0 Access Denied When Trying To Open Local Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339734/ie-8-0-access-denied-when-trying-to-open-local-files][1])

Is it possible to embbed an HTA application into a given xslt stylesheet? 
For example, given the present template:

```
<xsl:template match="/"> 
        <html>
            <head>
...
</head>
</html>
</xsl:template>
```

Is this theoretically correct?:

```
<xsl:template match="/"> 
        <html>
            <head>
<HTA:APPLICATION 
 APPLICATIONNAME="HTA Test"
 SCROLL="yes"
 SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
 WINDOWSTATE="maximize"
 >
</head>
</html>
</xsl:template>
```

Will the HTA work if **it is not explicitly saved** as a HTA file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to open the file explicitly with mshta.exe by passing the file name of your xslt file to mshta.exe.

For example:

```
mshta "S:\test.xslt"
```

You may have to write it as:

```
C:\Windows\System32\mshta.exe "S:\test.xslt"
```

or, to get the 32 bit version of mshta on a 64 bit OS:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mshta.exe "S:\test.xslt"
```

Comment: So, in fact, the stylesheet will be opened by mshta? Though, this stylesheet is invoked in an xml file for its styling purpose. So the chain would look like: Open xml, which automatically gets formatted by xslt stylesheet. 

Ironically, during writing this comment I already figured out my would-be question "How can I invoke stylesheet from xml file through the HTML host Application?" 
So I will modify my xml 
From this: 

'<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='S:\test.xslt'?>'
To this:

'<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='C:\Windows\System32\mshta.exe "S:\test.xslt"'?>'

Answer (score 1):

"Will the HTA work if it is not explicitly saved as a HTA file?" No, it does not work, a HTML application needs to be downloaded and saved on the local file system and then started from there.